# Injection of $\mathbb N$ into proper classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In ZFC, given a proper class, is it possible to prove there is injection of the natural numbers $\mathbb N$ into it?

If not, are there proper classes which do not have such injection?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

Recall the [**cumulative hierarchy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe): $V_0=\emptyset$, $V_\lambda=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}V_\alpha$ for $\lambda\in ON$ a limit, and $V_{\alpha+1}=\mathcal{P}(V_\alpha)$.

ZF alone proves (the crucial axioms are [*Foundation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) and [*Replacement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement)) that $V=\bigcup_{\alpha\in ON} V_\alpha$, and that each $V_\alpha$ is a set. *EDIT: the symbol "$V$" denotes the whole set-theoretic universe; so what I wrote above really means "ZF proves that every set $x$ is in some $V_\alpha$."* So if $C$ is a proper class, we must have that for every $\alpha\in ON$ there is a $\beta>\alpha$ such that $C\cap (V_\beta\setminus V_\alpha)\not=\emptyset$, that is, any proper class has elements of arbitrarily high **rank**.

So - without choice! - we can define an $\omega$-sequence of ordinals $\alpha_0<\alpha_1<\alpha_2< . . . $ such that for each $i$, there is an element of $C$ in $V_{\alpha_i+1}\setminus V_{\alpha_i}$. This in turn gives us - again without choice! - an $\omega$-sequence of sets $X_i$ such that

- $X_i\subset C$ and is nonempty for every $i$, and
- $X_i\cap X_j=\emptyset$ for $i\not=j$.

Now, apply choice to this sequence.

---

Note that there's no special role played by $\omega$ here; more generally, ZF proves that for any proper class $C$ and any ordinal $\gamma$, there is a sequence $\langle X_\alpha: \alpha<\gamma\rangle$ such that

- $X_\alpha\subset C$ and is nonempty for every $\alpha$, and
- $X_\alpha\cap X_\beta=\emptyset$ for $\alpha\not=\beta$.

Then, *in the presence of choice* we can extract an embedding from $\gamma$ into $C$.

---

And choice is, so far as I know, *necessary*. I suspect there is a model $W\models ZF$ and a definable-without-parameters proper class $C\subset W$ such that $W$ contains no injection from $\omega$ into $C$; put another way, for each set $x\in W$ the set $x\cap C$ is [**Dedekind-finite**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set). *However, I currently cannot show this*.

Another observation is that in fact ZF alone proves that any proper class surjects onto the ordinals (exercise, use the argument above). However, the ordinals need not *inject* into every proper class, *even with choice*! There are models of ZFC in which there are proper classes into which the ordinals do not embed. Instead, [*global choice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_global_choice) is needed here.

Comment: Definable ***without*** parameters? Do you have a reference? The only construction that comes to mind is Monro's class of Dedekind-finite sets, which I'm not sure is even definable as a ZF class in that model, but rather in extended language to include some class predicate, or in the NBG extension of the model.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You're right, I thought I had an argument for how to get this (roughly: start with $L$ and an inaccessible $\kappa$, add "Cohen" subsets of $\mu$ for each cardinal $\mu<\kappa$, take an appropriate symmetric submodel and cut it off at $\kappa$; now look at the class of "Cohen"-over-$L$ subsets of $L$-cardinals), but I'm no longer certain it works. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: I think that one of my recent projects might be an example. I'll think about it tomorrow morning (I have to fix some part of that construction anyway). But adding Cohen subsets is not going to do you much good, because I'm not sure there is a uniformly definable "generating" set of Cohens. It might work, though.

Comment: In any case, either this is what Monro did, and the class ends up being definable without parameters, or this is going to require something slightly more clever (perhaps iterating symmetric extensions can yield some nice example, but right now I'm a man with a hammer, so maybe it's not needed).

Comment: (Just to be clear, by the way, when I say Monro, I mean the result mentioned in my answer [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/83599/permutation-models-with-a-class-sized-group/83603#83603).)

Comment: I don't understand why is it that 
$$C\cap(V_\beta\setminus V_\alpha)$$ isn't empty (I don't understand why C is related somehow to the construction of V).

Comment: @availanche Suppose that $C\subseteq V_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$. Then by Separation, $C$ is in fact a set! So $C$ is *not* contained in any $V_\alpha$. This means that for each $\alpha$, there is some element $c\in C\setminus V_\alpha$. Now, this $c$ is itself in some $V_\beta$ (*remember - each set is in some $V_\gamma$!*) - so $c\in V_\beta\setminus V_\alpha$. That is: for every $\alpha$, there is some $\beta$ such that $C\cap (V_\beta\setminus V_\alpha)$ is nonempty.

Comment: I don't understand why C is a subclass of V ("this c is itself in some V_\beta").

Comment: @availanche $V$ is the whole set-theoretic universe. *Everything* is a subclass of $V$. I've added an edit to clarify this.

Comment: How do you show that $$\cap\phi$$ is V?

Comment: @availanche (I presume you mean "How do you show that $\bigcup V_\alpha=V$.) Suppose $x$ is not in any $V_\alpha$. Let $y$ be the *transitive closure* of $x$. (Showing that this exists uses Replacement.) Now let $z$ be the set of elements of $y$ which are not in any $V_\alpha$. Note: if $a$ is not in any $V_\alpha$, then $a$ must have an element which is not in any $V_\alpha$ (this is a good exercise - see Burali-Forti). So every element of $z$ contains another element of $z$. But this is a contradiction to the axiom of Foundation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44606/discussion-between-availanche-and-noah-schweber).

Comment: Noah, giving it some more thought, I still don't see how the class in Monro's example (which is similar to your construction, only without the inaccessible: we can take class symmetric models too!) is definable without parameters or without a new predicate symbol. Sure, it's enough to have a uniform definition with parameter $\kappa$. But I really don't see how one like that can exist. The problem is that a class-name which is definable only from the forcing (no parameters otherwise), and is stable under all the automorphisms used, is still not guaranteed to be a class of the symmetric model.

Comment: Noah, I don't understand your guidelines: if w is the set of ranks of elements of some alleged element z that is not in V, then w is set of ordinals, ordinals obey transitivity regardless of w and hence the relation "being element of" on elements of w is transitive relation. So the transitive closure is this relation already.

Comment: @availanche This is in response to showing $V=\bigcup V_\alpha$? I think you're misreading my argument. We start with $x\not\in \bigcup V_\alpha$, let $y$ be the transitive closure of $x$, and **now** let $z$ be the set of elements of $y$ which are not in $\bigcup V_\alpha$. Now we can prove that every element of $z$ contains another element of $z$, and this is a contradiction to Foundation. (We need $y$, as opposed to $x$, in order to guarantee that $z$ is also "transitive-ish" - if we applied this to just $x$, we wouldn't have $\forall k\in z(k\cap z\not=\emptyset)$. Does this make sense?

Comment: I think if you have more questions about this, you should look at a set theory text such as Kunen, where the argument is presented in detail.

Comment: I wasn't able to find related text in a PDF I found on the internet ("Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs").

Comment: @availanche I don't have Kunen on hand, but I believe it's in Chapter 3. Or, I know it's in Enderton, right after he introduces the axiom of foundation (and in fact Enderton's proof is contained in Alberto Takase's answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665098/axiom-of-regularity-and-ordinal-ranks). If that doesn't help, I think you should ask a separate question about this - this comment thread is **way** too long. :P